# How to get parent widget's name printed from child widget class?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I understand that question is simple, but I'm stuck anyway. 
Is there any method to get parent layout widget name from inherited widget class?

I have a small piece of code here. So basically I need to get printed `self.super_main_layout` in the label field where "Push the button" printed now.

I have a function def print_foo which should do that. But I don't know how to get `parent()` name from inherited class. I need to get exactly this `self.super_main_layout` printed in label field.

I've tried to use `self.parent()` method but it doesn't work

```
import sys 
from PyQt5  import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

class ButtonTest(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ButtonTest, self).__init__()

        self.setFixedSize(300, 100)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Push the Button")
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.print_foo)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def print_foo(self):
        ### ???????????
        self.label.setText(str(self.parent().parent())) # ????
        print(self.parent()) # ????

class MyApp(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()

        self.W = ButtonTest()

        self.setFixedSize(300,300)
        self.super_main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.super_main_layout)
        self.super_main_layout.addWidget(self.W)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyApp()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So now it prints None in label field when you push Button. 
But I want layout widget `self.super_main_layout` to be printed. 
Is there any way to do that? I'm working on a bigger project right now. And I'm programming only inherited class with button in which I have to get different parent names when button is pressed. 
Thank you very much.

ps. I'm quite new to this site and programming at all, so sorry for any mistakes. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of a variable is impossible in itself to obtain because the names of the variables are relative, for example if the code were the following:

```py
# ...
self.setFixedSize(300,300)
self.super_main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
foo_obj = self.super_main_layout
self.setLayout(foo_obj)
self.super_main_layout.addWidget(self.W)
```

What is the name of the layout: `self.super_main_layout` or `foo_obj`? As both variables refer to the same object.

What you can get is the object itself using the parent and then its layout:

```py
def print_foo(self):
    pw = self.parentWidget()
    if pw is not None:
        print(pw.layout())
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I understood. 
I'll try to use your method.
Thanks